# Argonaut casecodec3?

Tags: scala, argonaut

I'm trying this simple example from the Argonaut quickstart:

```
case class Address(street: String, number: Int, postcode: Int)

object Address {
  // Define codecs easily from case classes
  implicit def AddressCodecJson: CodecJson[Address] =
    casecodec3(Address.apply, Address.unapply)("street", "number", "post_code")
}
```

I'm getting a compilation error on `casecodec3`. I cloned the argonaut and scalaz repos and grepped the source, and I only see that in example code. Where is that symbol coming from and why can't I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your imports are in order then that should just work:

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._
case class Address(street: String, number: Int, postcode: Int)

object Address {
  implicit def AddressCodecJson: CodecJson[Address] =
  casecodec3(Address.apply, Address.unapply)("street", "number", "post_code")
}
```

In the REPL make sure to enter paste mode

```
scala> :paste 
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import argonaut._, Argonaut._
case class Address(street: String, number: Int, postcode: Int)

object Address {
  implicit def AddressCodecJson: CodecJson[Address] =
  casecodec3(Address.apply, Address.unapply)("street", "number", "post_code")
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Address
defined object Address
```

You don't see the source in github because the source is generated for example  `GeneratedCodecJsons.scala` as defined in the build here 
`https://github.com/argonaut-io/argonaut/blob/master/project/Boilerplate.scala`

Comment: thank you! I had defined a custom singleton object named `Argonaut` which introduced a name conflict that caused the problem.